# How to filter data inside subreport RDLC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I have a subreport inside report and i pass a parameter to the sub report `tutorUsername`.
My code when creating report is this:

```
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = (reportPath + "TestReport.rdlc");
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(prcProcessSubReport);
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("test_DataSet", report));
 ReportParameter[] tmpParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
 tmpParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("serverNames", serverNamesList, false);
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(tmpParameters);
```

And :

```
private void prcProcessSubReport(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
     try
      {
        string tutorUserName = e.Parameters["tutorusername"].Values[0].ToString();
        ReportDataSource rdsTradeDetails = new ReportDataSource("Test_DataSet", report);
        e.DataSources.Add(rdsTradeDetails);
        //Code End
      }
      catch (Exception eX)
      { 

      }

    }
```

Now the issue is i do get the parameter valye but its `(Fields!Tutor_Username.Value, \"TEST_DataSet\")` . I was assuming this way i will get the tutor username for each and i will create /filter datatable with the parameter and  add accordingly . Any help? What am i doing wrong is there some other way to get parameter value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT was simple had to do like this :

```
 string tutorUserName = (e.Parameters["tutorusername"].Values.First()).ToString();
 ReportDataSource rdsTradeDetails = new ReportDataSource("Test_DataSet", report);
 e.DataSources.Add(rdsTradeDetails);
```